Setup project installs itself but not the VSTO Add-in
I followed this tutorial to create a custom installer for my VSTO Excel Add-in.
The reason I want to do that is because I need custom operations before the Add-in is installed and after the Add-in is uninstalled.
By following the above tutorial, I was able to build the installer, but running the installer does not install the Add-in.

The process completes successfuly. It actually does something but it appears all it does is it generates some files in C:\Program Files (x86)

The Addin is not visible in Excel.
Would anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

There might be several reasons why the addin is not visible in excel. Could you check this blog, here are various reasons/checks why it might not be there: TroubleShooting
